# Turn off colour while using script(1)

Tags: command-line, scripts, vim, colors

Is there a way to turn off colour while using script(1)? My script file is being filled with unnecessary information regarding colours from commands such as ls. This information is only visible when using text editors such as vim and arguably gedit. I'm not looking to do a search and replace, but rather stop the issue before it happens. Is there a way to remove the ^M line feed characters by default as well?

I have included a sample script file:

```
Script started on Mon 05 May 2014 10:58:33 PM ADT                               
^M^M                                                                            
$ ls^M                                                                          
^[[0m^[[01;34mBin^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDesktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  examples.desktop  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[    [0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  test.txt  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^M^M                                                                            
$ exit^M                                                                        
exit^M                                                                          

Script done on Mon 05 May 2014 10:58:50 PM ADT
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
$ script test.txt
Script started, file is test.txt

$ ls
Bin  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  test.txt  Videos

$ exit
exit
Script done, file is test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for ls, you can use

```
ls --color=never
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested but realized I would need to track down all the possible sources of color like commands, the command prompt itself, etc. This is a sed filter from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed) that works great if you pipe anything through it. Of course you can save the output once piped like this:

```
cat test.txt | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" > new-test.txt
```